# In which cases is this set compact?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$, $b \in \mathbb R^m$. I'm trying to analyze when the following set
$$M := \{ x \in \mathbb R^n_+: Ax\leq b\}$$
is compact.
So far, I've found that if $Ax = b$ has a unique solution, it should lie in the first orthant for $M$ to be compact. Moreover, if $Ax = b$ does not have a solution or if it has infinite solutions, then all the components $a_{ij}$ of $A$ and $b_k$ of $b$ should be positive. Is my reasoning correct or is there something that I missing?

Comment: By "$Ax=b$ has a unique solution" do you mean solution for $x\in\Bbb R^n$, or for $x\in\Bbb R^n_+$?

Comment: @nicomezi: Sorry, my bad.

Comment: @Gae.S.: In $\mathbb R^n$ (than it can be checked if it lies in the $\mathbb R^n_+$).

Comment: It is clearly closed, so you just have to see whether it is bounded.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to check. However, I'm still not sure if the cases that I mentioned are the only ones in which $M$ is bounded.